# PHP AWS DynamoDB: Limit the Number of Total Query Results Using an Iterator

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to limit the total number of results that can come back with an iterator to 3. Not the number of results for each iteration. I am hoping to make this number dynamic. However, I cannot find any real answer to accomplish this and the documentation that AWS provides is of no help. Putting the Limit inside array with the table name and keys doesn't limit the results. I also put it in its own separate array but that doesn't work either. The below is what I have tried but I have not been able to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$iterator = $dbh->getIterator('Query', array(
        'TableName'     => 'raw',
        'KeyConditions' => array(
            'deviceID' => array(
                'AttributeValueList' => array(
                    array('S' => $deviceID)
                ),
                'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
            )
        ),
        'ScanIndexForward' => false   // true = ascending, false = descending
    ),
    array(
        'Limit' => 3 
    )
);
```

Then putting the resulting data into an array. I don't know if I need to do something different here?

```
foreach ($iterator as $item) {
     array_push($resultArray, $item);
}
```

Comment: Can you try this and see what happens. `foreach (new LimitIterator($iterator, 0, 3) as $item) {
    array_push($resultArray, $item);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You might have already tried this, by the looks of it, but try your code with lowercase 'limit'.

```
 $iterator = $dbh->getIterator('Query', array(
        'TableName'     => 'raw',
        'KeyConditions' => array(
            'deviceID' => array(
                'AttributeValueList' => array(
                    array('S' => $deviceID)
                ),
                'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
            )
        ),
        'ScanIndexForward' => false   // true = ascending, false = descending
    ),
    array(
        'limit' => 3 
    )
);
```

You could also try limiting by doing below.

```
foreach (new LimitIterator($iterator, 0, 3) as $item) {
    array_push($resultArray, $item); 
}
```

Comment: @applecrusher did this work for you, especially with LimitIterator it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its sets the Limit once inside the params, which should limit the query results, and then once outside the params, which should limit the iterator size

```
$iterator = $dbh->getIterator('Query', array(
        'TableName'     => 'raw',
        'KeyConditions' => array(
            'deviceID' => array(
                'AttributeValueList' => array(
                    array('S' => $deviceID)
                ),
                'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
            )
        ),
        'ScanIndexForward' => false,   // true = ascending, false = descending
        'Limit' => 3 
    ),
    array(
        'limit' => 3,
        'page_size' => 3 
    )
);
```

Make sure the argument outside of the params is 'limit' (lowercase) and inside it is 'Limit' (starts with a capital).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also something else I tried and this didn't working either.

Comment: Just to check, the code you posted had the incorrect capitalisation of Limit. Did you lowercase this?

Comment: I did, I copy and pasted your code above. I just tried it again and it's still not limiting the results.

Comment: What are you getting in the results?

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Thank you for all the help and effort you put into this!